# Multiple tabs on chrome won't open when submit form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome

I need my codes to open two new tabs for two different report from two different forms when a button with onclick="submitReport()", it works on mozilla but won't work on chrome. These are my codes

JSP:

```
<form action="<%=accessReport%>" id="Report1" name="Report1" method="post" target="_blank">
        <input type="hidden" name="path1" id="path1" value=":home:ecosadmin:MainFolder:File1.prpt"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="idReport1" id="idReport1" value="<%=idReport%>"/>
    </form>

<form action="<%=accessReport%>" id="Report2" name="Report2" method="post" target="_blank">   
        <input type="hidden" name="idReport2" id="idReport2" value="<%=idReport%>">         
        <input type=hidden name="path2" id="path2" value=":home:ecosadmin:MainFolder:ReportFile2.prpt">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function submitReport(){
   document.forms['Report1'].submit();
   document.forms['Report2'].submit();
}
</script>
```

I hope someone can provide some ideas how to make it works on chrome

Comment: There is nothing java related here.... java and javascript are completely different things.

Comment: yeah i know.. maybe there is an misunderstanding here.. actually i want to know how to make this codes works on chrome too since its working on mozilla..chrome just won't open the new tabs and i think there is nothing wrong with the codes..so im confused y its still does not work

Comment: Check whether google chrome is blocking pop-up window or not.

Comment: i changed the setting in chrome to allow pop-up, but still not working.. i read about changing the target from _blank to iframe...but still not working in my case.. it only opens one new tab, not two

Comment: I think this problem also in chrome, a form submit two time with different parameter, only one tab for the first submit parameter is shown